# Adding interactive legend in d3.js for vijuly weighted tree

Tags: d3.js

i am new to d3,this may seem very silly question for those using D3 . However i am trying to implement this  http://vizuly.io/product/weighted-tree/.
I  am trying to make a interactive legend which filters the tree when legend are clicked.
However i am not able to figure out the tree data structure ,how to pass the viz object in legend ,how to make filtering work.

i want to collapse all nodes except the one whose legend i have clicked.

```html
function onClickLegend(g,d){      // for filtering or collapsing that node and corresponding branches whose legend is clicked
   switch(d)
       { 
     case 0: viz.toggleNode(data.values[0]); break;
        case 1: viz.toggleNode(data.values[1]); break;
        case 2: viz.toggleNode(data.values[2]); break;
        case 3: viz.toggleNode(data.values[3]); break;
        case 4: viz.toggleNode(data.values[4]); break;
        case 5: viz.toggleNode(data.values[5]); break;
        case 6: viz.toggleNode(data.values[6]); break;
        case 7: viz.toggleNode(data.values[7]); break;
        case 8: viz.toggleNode(data.values[8]); break;
        case 9: viz.toggleNode(data.values[9]); break;
  case 10: viz.toggleNode(data.values[10]); break;
  case 11: viz.toggleNode(data.values[11]); break;
  case 12: viz.toggleNode(data.values[12]);break;
       
     
  }  
    
}
```

Comment: Show us the working code that creates the graph, and i can provide some help. Also, the legend should be created in d3, and not vanilla js.

Comment: I have figured the above ,however there is a problem with filtering .

Comment: The problem of filtering is solved after ,i used collapse function and in switch case i used collapse on all the nodes except the click.